# Copy table data without linked servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

We have a SQL Server 2008 database and I need to copy data from several tables to a SQL Server 2005 database after truncating the tables in 2005.

I've used the import/export wizard and that works. However, I don't have permissions to save the package.

These are also not linked servers (and can't be made to be).

My question is, is there someway to add this to my truncate table script and exceute it in mgmt studio?  It is a pain having to go through that wizard every week.

This is a corporate environment so getting additional permissions, setup is not really viable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your only option is to ask corporate to build you an SSIS package to do the data transfer, and then have them schedule it as a SQL Server Agent job to run once a week.

An SSIS package with a .dtsx file extension is what the Import/Export wizard would have saved, if you had permission to save a file on the database server.  However, IT will probably build this from scratch in Visual Studio / BIDS, and it will take them much longer to document the requirements, etc, etc, than would have taken you to just save the package.